# ERROR SonarQube Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging

Tags: visual-studio-code, sonarqube, visual-studio-debugging, sonarqube-scan

Hi i have my project in VSC and when i try to run in the terminal the command line:

```
sonar-scanner.bat -D"sonar.projectKey=***" -D"sonar.sources=." -D"sonar.host.url=***" -D"sonar.login=***"
```

to analyse my code VSC terminal displays this error:

```
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
org.sonar.java.AnalysisException: Your project contains .java files, please provide compiled classes with sonar.java.binaries property, or exclude them from the analysis with sonar.exclusions property.
        at org.sonar.java.classpath.ClasspathForMain.init(ClasspathForMain.java:75)
        at org.sonar.java.classpath.AbstractClasspath.getElements(AbstractClasspath.java:319)
        at org.sonar.java.SonarComponents.getJavaClasspath(SonarComponents.java:204)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaFrontend.<init>(JavaFrontend.java:95)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSensor.execute(JavaSensor.java:112)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:64)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(SpringModuleScanContainer.java:81)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringProjectScanContainer.scan(SpringProjectScanContainer.java:392)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(SpringProjectScanContainer.java:388)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(SpringProjectScanContainer.java:357)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.SpringGlobalContainer.doAfterStart(SpringGlobalContainer.java:135)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong, i have my token, i select Other (for JS, TS, Go, Python, PHP, ...) > Windows and Execute the Scanner in the VSC terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that you have not provided the java binaries during the sonar execution.

Add the below sonar.properties:

```
sonar.java.binaries= **/*.java
```

This will now scan your java binaries. This property is one of the required property if you are going to scan the java code.